# How can I execute a powershell script on a remote machine?

Tags: powershell

How can I execute a powershell script on a remote machine?

Do I have to go through winrm?

Answer (score 2):

[PowerShell Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is probably the method of choice here. [Tobias Weltner has written a short free eBook on the topic.](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/news/archive/2010/03/03/administrator-s-guide-to-powershell-remoting.aspx)